# Typescript Assertion Signatures and Promises

Tags: typescript

I'm using Typescript 3.7 assertion signatures, and they're great!  But I want to use them in async functions as well, and I'm getting an error:

`Type 'void' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.`

It would make sense if assertion signatures didn't work with asynchronous functions since Typescript would need to evaluate whether the Promise resolved or not, but I wasn't sure if there was an official stance on whether or not it was supported.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't supported.  Type assertion functions can't return any value, and async functions always return a promise.

You can follow https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34636 if this issue affects you or for more discussion of the issue.

The [original PR that introduced type assertions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34636) says that "A function call is analyzed as an assertion call or never-returning call when the call occurs as a top-level expression statement" (among other conditions).  That rules out promises because a promise would either need to be part of an `await` expression or an assignment expression rather than a top-level expression statement.